# Where does Joomla store page selection for modules?

Tags: joomla, module, settings

In Joomla, when you select the pages that a module will appear on, where are those settings stored? I haven't been able to find them in the database, so I'm suspecting they are stored elsewhere for some reason. I checked specifically in 1.5's database, but any version will be fine. I believe they are all the same in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.0 there is a table called `#__modules_menu` that stores all the associations. I believe if the menuid is 0 that means all pages, greater than one is just the selected, less than one means all except selected, and no record for the module means no pages.